# App like Lightroom and Photos to display geotagged images in a map

Tags: macos, photos, software-recommendation, gps

I am looking for a Mac app to display locations of the geotagged photos in a folder using google maps.

- I don't want to import them from Photos because:
  a)  It is not practical to import several large images (10Mb+), get the info I am looking for (for example clicking on one of the sample thumbnails to see which photos were took in that place) and then delete all of them at the end.
  Why that? Because I don't want Photos Library increased (it is linked to iCloud)
  [image: Places of Photos].
  b) I don't like encapsulated data, specially because I access image folders from other computers in other OS.
- I know it is possible using Lightroom but I am looking for a solution where I don’t have to pay majority of the features when I want just a map.
- an interactive map where I can see images and explore them is a needed function

Edit 1:
Google Maps because it seems to me that it has more information. I also has Street

Comment 1: I am having a very simplified screen, no way to just put a thumbnail instead of a large photo, no preview screen

Answer (score 1):

Check out [HoudahGeo](https://www.houdah.com/houdahGeo/) — it's an inexpensive Mac app that lets you easily drag and drop photos to view on a map, edit location info, etc.

Comment: Good app but I cannot see the way to get which photo corresponds to a pin I touch like in Lightroom.
I mean, I select several image files so several pins are spread in the map. I want to click on certain pin and discover to which image file it corresponds

Comment: @dstonek If you check out the [HoudahGeo User Guide] (https://www.houdah.com/houdahGeo/help/5.2/HoudahGeo%20Help%20EN.pdf) there are instructions on how you can export your photos and GPS data to a folder (see 3.3.3 KML Export) — upload those to your Dropbox or Google Drive and then you can use Google My Maps to display them all on a clickable map with enlargeable thumbnail images. Maybe not the smoothest method but it gets the job done. Good luck!